# VAEs - getting an equivalent sample?

Tags: vae

I'm trying to learn/experiment with VAEs(I'm a complete beginner).

If I get a probability distribution Q closely similar to the original distribution P using a VAE, would it be possible to find a sample on the new distribution (Q) that is equivalent to a sample on the original distribution (P) ? Or would that be impossible due to epsilon adding randomness ? How would I go about achieving this ? In essence, my goal would not be generating new data, my goal would be finding the same sample on a different distribution.

My apologies if this is a ridiculous question.